# setmyLocation(true) not working. Have already put all the location permissions in manifest

Tags: android

I'm using mapbox sdk to find user's location but none of these functions work:
My manifest has Accessfinelocation and coarselocation permission already.

```
setMyLocationEnabled(true)
setUserLocationTrackingMode()
setUserLocationRequiredZoom(10);
getUserLocation();

MapView mv = (MapView)  findViewById(R.id.mapView);
MapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mapView.setUserLocationTrackingMode(UserLocationOverlay.TrackingMode.FOLLOW);
mapView.setUserLocationRequiredZoom(10);


mapView.getUserLocation();
```

Comment: If you're running your app in android 6.0 or later, you should also request the permissions in the runtime.

Comment: I'm not running in android 6.0